# Who was Aozaki talking about when she said Ryougi?

Tags: the-garden-of-sinners

In the 3rd movie, *The Garden of Sinners: Remaining Sense of Pain*, Aozaki is staring out the window and talking to herself after Shiki leaves. Who is she talking about when she says Ryougi, since she already called Shiki by name in the same sentence?

> **Touko Aozaki**: Shiki might end up being killed instead if she goes alone, Ryougi.

This happens at around 27:55.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just frivolous subtitling? Sometimes writers choose to call the same person by their first and then last name just to avoid repetition.

Comment: @Hakase She says both names in the audio as well.

Comment: Have you seen all the movies? If not, do that first. There's a reason.

Comment: @senshin Ok, ^_^ I'll finish the rest of them tonight.

Comment: it's been a while since i've seen the movies so i can't recall what part of the movie what you mention is from but chronologically wise the third movie is set after she wakes from the coma, after SHIKI has sacrificed himself to save her. it could be that Touko is calling SHIKI Ryougi and because Shiki has been feeling lost ever since she woke up without SHIKI so it could be Touko is worried about Shiki find a way to get SHIKI back as stated in the wikia *"She hopes to regain herself and the "dead" SHIKI"*

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that

> Aozaki may know the existence of "the Void", another personality which never surfaced.

However I can't find evidence showing that Aozaki really knows about it.

Comment: actually to correct you the third personality did make an appearance before and that was when Kokuto first met Shiki on the road

Comment: @Memor-X yeah I feel Kokuto would be the only one knowing its existence, otherwise the thematic impact would be less.

Comment: oh i was only correcting the *"which never surfaced"* part which chronologically it had before